# Does mysql UPDATE inserts the values if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE items SET name = 'haha' WHERE id = '12'
```

I'm curious if update also inserts the values if the where condition fails. I've read on w3schools that update only updates **existing** data on the database but on my script it's automatically inserting rows with the data. I am wondering if it might be a bug in the script or that's just how UPDATE works on mysql.

Comment: insert creates data, update updates existing data and delete...well...you get the idea. Could you show us your script, please?

Comment: Clarify what you mean. What you read is correct, how is your script "automatically" creating the data? Sample queries and results would be nice

Comment: this is a perfect example of a badly asked question. what is table structure? what is your query? what is newly created data?

Comment: If you want to update/insert depending on the conditions, either use a `replace` or `insert ... on duplicate key update` statement.

Answer (score 18):

No. If, in your example, there's no entry with id = 12 in the database, the query will return "no rows affected". An update will never create a new entry in MySQL.

EDIT: although update won't create a new entry, it may include default/automatic values set up in your database schema (current timestamp, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

NO. Update does not insert a value if the value doesn't exist in table. Please check if the script checks if the status of the update and makes another call to DB to insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should do the following -

Update all records in the items table that have an id of 12 by setting their name to 'haha'

Update won't insert records if they don't exist, it will only update existing records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: If your column doesn't exist you will get an error. If your where condition column doesn't exist you get error too. If your where condition value doesn't exist, it do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I use a temp table to review the data update conditions, you can refer

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET 
        column1 = 'things' 
    WHERE 
        IDcolumn = 'id' AND 
        (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) AS temp WHERE temp.column1 = N'things'))
```